# Mapping an array of objects, but need to map object response

Tags: reactjs, javascript-objects, react-table, data-transform

I am relatively new to React I am trying to figure out the best way to transform some API response that is being returned in an axios call. I know this question most likely exists in other spaces, but I can't seem to find an answer that clearly explains what I am trying to do. Thank you in advance to anyone who can give me a solid lead on this, or easy to understand documentation.

I am working on building a `react-table` where I need some data, to be shown but also need to make some data transformations happen, prior to the data being passed to the table.

note: I am not allowed to edit the server so I can't make the logic calls on the backend
This is the response.

```
  {
  "id": "0e022ed0",
  "start_date": "2014-01-17T06:12:47.566+05:00",
  "request_date": "2014-01-17T05:46:08.542+06:00",
  "end_date": "2014-01-18T02:15:34.721+05:00",
  "status": "The system reports success",
  "total": 56,
  "processed": 56,
  "username": "JimJimmerson",
  "fullname": "Jim Jimmerson",
  "email": "example@gmail.com"
},
```

I'd like my data to look something like this:

```
 {
    "id": "0e022ed0",
    "start_date": "2014-01-17T06:12:47.566+05:00",
    "request_date": "2014-01-17T05:46:08.542+06:00",
    "end_date": "2014-01-18T02:15:34.721+05:00",
    "progress": {
        "total": 56,
        "processed": 56,
        "status": { 
            "success": "The system reports success",
            "error": "Has start and end date, but not processed",
            "inactive": "No start date",
            "inProgress": "Has start date, processing hasn't finished"
        },
    },
    "user": {
        "username": "JimJimmerson",
        "fullname": "Jim Jimmerson",
        "email": "example@gmail.com"
    }
  }
```

Here is how I am getting the data:
note: the `options` being passed is just api-key

```
const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);
const [ progress, setProgress ] = useState('');
useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
        await axios.get(`${API_URL}${1}`, options)
        .then((resp) => {
            const data = resp.data.DATA;
            console.log('Response after call', data);
            setData(data);
            setLoadingData(false);
        })
    }
    if(loadingData) {
        getData();
    }
}, )
```

I started looking at Mapping the values of the object array, but I think I am having some confusion, with how other people are handling this / me not having a solid understanding of mapping values.

So I tried to write this helper method, after the data is returned

```
 const transformedTableData = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(data).map(([progress, processed, total]) => [
        progress,
        { ...data, progress: [processed, total] }
    ]),
)
```

I believe if I can get a solid explanation to this, I could figure out the other parts.
I'm most likely going about this in all of the wrong ways

The reason I need to do this is in `react-table` I'm not sure how to merge column values. I want to create a component that handles it. I know that you can pass the value of the cell to a component as a prop, but it seems that I can only pass that cells value. But not the values of multiple cells

```
{
    Header: 'total',
    accessor: 'total',
    Cell: ({ cell: {value}}) => <ProgressTracker values={value}/>
},
{
     Header: 'processed',
     accessor: 'processed',
     Cell: ({ cell: {value}})=><ProgressTracker values={value}/>
},
```

Comment: Are the values for keys `error`, `inactive` etc hard coded? Eg. `"No start date"`

Comment: They are currently hardcoded, I eventually want them to go `if (process === total && !end_date ) { return success }` where success is just a hard coded value that says success for the time being. May modify it more later to `success processed: ${processed} out of ${total}`

Answer (score 1):

Heres a quick example of `Object.entries` that might clarify some stuff:

```
const data = {
  id: "0e022ed0",
  start_date: "2014-01-17T06:12:47.566+05:00",
  request_date: "2014-01-17T05:46:08.542+06:00",
  end_date: "2014-01-18T02:15:34.721+05:00",
  status: "The system reports success",
  total: 56,
  processed: 56,
  username: "JimJimmerson",
  fullname: "Jim Jimmerson",
  email: "example@gmail.com",
};

Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(key, value);
  // do something with key and value and return
});
```

This will log out

```
id 0e022ed0
start_date: "2014-01..."
...
```

However, since what you want at the end of the day is an object that has a different shape, I wouldnt suggest using map here. Map lets you change how each element of an array looks, so if you looped over the entires, you modify what each looks like.

In this scenario, I would do something like this:

```
const data = {
  id: "0e022ed0",
  start_date: "2014-01-17T06:12:47.566+05:00",
  request_date: "2014-01-17T05:46:08.542+06:00",
  end_date: "2014-01-18T02:15:34.721+05:00",
  status: "The system reports success",
  total: 56,
  processed: 56,
  username: "JimJimmerson",
  fullname: "Jim Jimmerson",
  email: "example@gmail.com",
};

const { total, processed, username, fullname, email, ...rest } = data;

const result = {
  ...rest,
  progress: {
    total,
    processed,
    status: {
      // whatever
    },
  },
  user: {
    username,
    fullname,
    email,
  },
};
```

Comment: thank you, that worked. appreciate the explanation